# Kivy on a Raspberry Pi 2 with Python 3.4

Tags: python, kivy, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I followed all of the steps when installing Kivy on my Raspberry Pi 2 with Python 3.4, but whenever I try to run a program that imports kivy.app it gives me this error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-11-25_23.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1-dev
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.4.3 (default, Nov 25 2015, 16:21:36) 
[GCC 4.6.3]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 319, in <module>
     from kivy.base import runTouchApp, stopTouchApp
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 29, in <module>
     from kivy.clock import Clock
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 278, in <module>
     _default_time = _libc_clock_gettime_wrapper()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 258, in _libc_clock_gettime_wrapper
     _clock_gettime = _libc.clock_gettime
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/ctypes/__init__.py", line 364, in __getattr__
     func = self.__getitem__(name)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/ctypes/__init__.py", line 369, in __getitem__
     func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
 AttributeError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: undefined symbol: clock_gettime
```

I've tried looking this up for hours but couldn't find anything. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this error was recently introduced in kivy master, and as such should be fixed soon. bionoid on irc suggested that ed0247031c56950dc506959d66457713d2923cdb is a working commit to try.

Comment: Thanks! I synced from that commit and everything worked.